# Apache NIFI with mssql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, apache, etl, apache-nifi

i need to use mssql stored procedure with param in nifi and get output from that stored procedure is any processor is available with run stored procedure and return the out put in avro schema or any other formate?

Comment: try ExecuteSQL. should work

Comment: i am using ExecuteSQL but i am not able to run a whole procedure in that one can u just told me the flow to setup for using excutesql to correct manner for stored procedure

Comment: just start from some static parameters. for mssql you can even use declare-begin-end code blocks. debug your call from sql-developer or whatever tool you are using